# Does std::swap of smart pointers guarantee the references to be unchanged?

Tags: c++, boost, swap

**Does std::swap of smart pointers guarantee the references (address in memory) to be unchanged?**

The *std* documentation states that one (of several) qualifying traits for letting `class T` be swap-able, is that,

> T must be assignable and T must be copy and/or move constructible

If swaping was conducted by the use of copy construction, I would suspect that the memory addresses might change. However, I also suspect that swapping by copy construction is not relevant when swapping specifically (smart) pointers.

The below code compiles (GCC) and runs smoothly without changing the address upon swapping, but do I have a guarantee for this to be so?

**Note:** Example is using `std::auto_ptr` because it was pointed out in comments that *std* code is preferable over boost. I work on old C++ and do not have `std::unique_ptr` available (which nevertheless have its copy constructor deleted). Original post applied `boost::scoped_ptr`.

```cpp
#include <boost/scoped_ptr>
#include <iostream>

class Awesome
{
public:
    Awesome(int a=0) : Value(a) {}
    Awesome(const Awesome& T) : Value(T.Value) {}
    int Value;
};

int main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<Awesome> a_ptr(new Awesome(2));
    Awesome& a_ref = *a_ptr.get();

    std::cout << "a_ptr's addr : " << a_ptr.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a_ref's addr : " << &a_ref << std::endl;

    std::auto_ptr<Awesome> b_ptr;
    std::swap(b_ptr, a_ptr); // <<------------------ Does this (possibly) break 'a_ref' ?

    std::cout << "b_ptr's addr : "<< b_ptr.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would be a *much* better question if it was posed with `std::swap`.

Comment: @Bathsheba .. noted. I will edit then, but I will really be using boost.

Comment: The reason of course is that Boost is not standardised, so it makes the question difficult to answer. Out of interest, why can't you use `std::swap`? Whilst I love Boost, whenever features make it to standard C++, I always migrate.

Comment: Because I'm working on old code which is not written by me. I'm not about to cast all my boost pointers to std. But I will edit the question: I agree that std-questions are better for SO.

Comment: No, as far as the object is not out of scope, the reference a_ref will be valid.

Comment: Don't use `auto_ptr` ... It doesn't exist anymore in C++17.

Comment: @L.F. Please read the entire question .. I don't use `std::auto_ptr` .. I use `boost::scoped_ptr` , but som other guy wanted the question to be for std and not boost.. I write older than C++11, and don't have `std::unique_ptr` available.

Comment: Both `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` have a member function `swap` which `std::swap` is specialised to use (delegate to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are swapping pointers, not the objects themselves, the swap() function cannot change the address of the objects as it doesnt even know about the objects.
If you are looking for guarantee then you should ask for a guarantee that destroying and moving/copying the smart pointer doesnt affect the object.

edit: This is relevant to `std::swap(b_ptr, a_ptr);` , in boost there is a member function swap on the smart pointers so in theory it could do anything, but i highly doubt that it would change the address of the object when swapping pointers.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on the boost member swap. I did not think of that. I agree that it is highly unlikely to do anything dubvious, however, it is nice to keep in mind, and I will check its implementation.